# How to fix when Calling disabled() on FormControlName makes entire form invalid?

Tags: angular, typescript

I am using reactive form, when i make formControlName disabled(), then entire form makes invalid.i want to valid after disabled.

```
  console.log('Before:'+ (this.form.valid));
  this.form.controls['formControlName1'].disable();//calling in onInit()
  console.log('After:'+(this.form.valid));

  output-:
  Before:true
  After:false.
```

Comment: can you create stackblitz

Comment: Do you want to disable all fields of your form or just selected?

Comment: just selected field i want disabled.

Comment: You are using **Angular 4!!**. In Angular 7, Angular don't check a control that is disabled

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
formControlName.disable({onlySelf: true});
```

Comment: Check out this. I have done form check on submit button.
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-reactive-forms-wpqmb1